# Mail not sent from https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, email

After placing my site on https, mail function not working.
code for https is placed in htacess
my site was on http and i placed it on https , but then i am receiving mail from site ( site is on wordpress using contact form 7 and php mail function on some pages )

Comment: can you post some code please?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.webmaster-talk.com/php-forum/56246-send-email-using-ssl.html#post268006